# how i can disable delete file option in unison sync tool?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, rsync, synchronization, unison

i want to disable delete option of `unison` in other word i want `unison` tool always copy file [don't delete anything]. I read manual but i can not find what i need .

for example we have two folder `folder1` and `folder2`

1- the first time :- folder1 contain text.txt

2- run unison :- text.txt copied to folder2

3- delete text.txt from folder2

4- run unison :- the current case file text.txt deleted from folder1 but i want to copy text.txt again to folder1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unison is a 2-ways synchronization tool. If you only want to synchronize in one-way, take a look at `--force`, `--prefer` option or use `rsync` for alternative.

Answer (score 2):

There's now a `-nodeletion` option that prevents unison from deleting files on one of the roots, or to both roots if you need that.